# Get string length from input buffer 8086

Tags: assembly, x86

Assuming you've read some ascii text into a character buffer of length say, 255 . How can you retrieve the length of the ascii text stored in the buffer into a CX register? (EDITED)

Thanks

Comment: How is the end of the string marked?

Comment: Find the first `\0` byte. Remember its offset from the start of the string. There's even an instruction, I think. Look for `REP STR...`

Comment: CX register is too narrow for ascii text. Maybe you want to get string length into CX -- then, is the string null-terminated? Please edit your question.

Comment: @AntonKovalenko you're right i meant the length of the string.. apologies.. It is terminated with a '$' sign.

Comment: @JerryCoffin the end is marked with a dollar sign '$'

Comment: @mac007 then look for the first `$`. The rest of my comment still applies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for the '$' using `rep scasb`, then subtract to get the distance from the beginning of the string.

```
; warning: untested code.
mov di, offset buffer
mov al, '$'
mov cx, 255
repnz scasb
sub di, offset buffer
mov cx, di
```

Comment: okay thanks.. but is there a way to do this on a single line of code?

Comment: @mac007: no, I don't think so. In assembly language, you generally shouldn't expect to do much in a single line of code (except, perhaps, by invoking a macro or something on that order, and it's open to question whether that qualifies as a single line of code).

Comment: No it doesn't :) `scasb` uses `al` not `ah`

Answer (score 1):

```
; STRLEN
LEA SI,PARA
MOV CX,-1
DO:
    LODSB
    INC CX
    CMP AL,0
    JNE DO
```